# Adding back layer heading in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, layers

I deleted the layer heading thinking that I didn't need it. But after doing some refactoring, it turns out that I do need it but I can't figure out any way to add it back.

How do I add it back?

I'm using ArcMap 10.6.

[image]

Comment: You can certainly create a new layer with the same source and resymbolize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the layer heading.

Go to symbology.
Change the value field to something else.
Change it back.

It should reappear.

The proper way is

Make sure the layer has headings. ...
Double-click the legend to open the Legend Properties dialog box and select the Items tab.
Click Style.
Click Properties.
Select the General tab.
Choose a heading from the 'Only show classes from this heading' dropdown list.

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002820

Comment: Any way to do this without losing the symbology? (Although, admittedly, making a copy of the layer and importing the symbology from that layer isn't too hard either...but that takes the heading away again...)